# traversing element content with jquery and greasemonkey

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

I have a question about traversing a newly created element with jquery and greasemonkey.

I have this javascript snippet:

```
var content="some html string"
var el = $( '<div></div>' );
el.html(content);
GM_log(el.html());
```

The html string I added to the new div is something like:

```
Hello:<br> world<br> <img src="someimage.jpg" align="absmiddle" border="0">
<font color="#FF0000"> hello<br>
<img src="otherimage.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0"> 
test</font><br>    
----------
```

I am looking for a way to traverse the newly created div and access each tag/text separately .
for example, if I do:

```
GM_log(el.children());
```

I can only access the whole children instead of the single pieces of text/tag.
Can anyone suggest me how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find('*')` to get all children and [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to traverse them.

```
el.find('*').each(function(){
    alert(this.tagName);
    alert($(this).html());
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: ok, one more question, your solution only displays the tag name, how do I access the text of that tag?or the html?

Comment: $(this).html() or $(this).text() or this.innerHTML

Comment: mm it seems it does not work: $(this).html() shows empty strings except for the img tags. I might have find the culprit. If I do  GM_log($(this)[0]) I get: 
[object XrayWrapper [object HTMLBRElement]] and XrayWrapper seems not to have an innerHTML implementation :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to fetch all descendant elements not just the direct children of the target element

```
GM_log(el.find('*'));
```